# Windows 10 home can I setup sstp server with new incoming connection?

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, sstp

I followed this guide to setup a vpn server on windows 10 home
https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/

I forwarded the port on my router and PPTP is working.
Next I was playing around with openvpn on port 80 since port 1723 might be blocked and noticed that by following the guide the server was also listening on 443 to use SSTP.

I find it really interesting to be able to connect via port 443, but SSTP uses certificates. All the guides I found, are for windows server.

Is it possible to setup a SSTP server on windows 10 home?

Comment: "Is it possible to setup an SSTP server on windows 10 home?" - Yes;

Comment: Great! Could you point me in the right direction. All guides for generating self signed certificates etc were for windows server with wizards from windows server. I didn't find a simple enough tutorial on how to get it the work with new incoming connection for home edition.

Comment: is there any news about? I have installed a "new incoming connection" but it works only with PPTP, I cannot connect as SSTP